# Where is dovecot installed on Mac?

Tags: macos, dovecot

I am attempting to set up pop3 and smtp server on my mac mini (OS X 10.15.7, Catalina).

I found postfix already installed based on the fact that "com.apple.postfix.master.plist" and "com.apple.postfix.newaliases.plist" files in /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ directory. In addition, "main.cf" and "master.cf" files are in /etc/postfix/ directory.
I then searched dovecot on my mac and I cannot find .plist nor any configure files.
However, "_dovecot" user exists as a result of the command "dscl . list /Users."

Could anyone tell me how I can find pre-installed dovecot on mac?
Or, should I install dovecot by myself, for example, through Homebrew or something?

I am asking this question in order to avoid any discrepancy or confusion caused by installing dovecot other than the preinstalled one.

Thank you in advance for any reply.

Answer (score 0):

Used to come bundled with [OS X Server](https://help.apple.com/advancedserveradmin/mac/3.1/#apdDCC9970C-9253-47C4-8152-7A5272CF753E) but that was ages ago and you mentioned that you are running Catalina, so not likely.

The user you found is present on a clean Big Sur installation as well, probably remnant from the past.

You can safely `brew install dovecot`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It confused me for a few months. Now I know _dovecot is not a valid user.